# Mobile-incompatibility with CSS

Tags: css, mobile

Something to do with this code is making my website not work on mobile. I have a `div` in the first line of the body in order to set a rotating set of backgrounds when loaded and when clicked, which are blurred, and then the real image upfront in the span. I wish I knew what was wrong with the code. But, if I can't find a solution, is there any way to disable a certain range of my CSS code on mobile platforms?

```
div {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  background-size:cover;
  -webkit-filter: blur(50px);
  -moz-filter: blur(50px);
  -o-filter: blur(50px);
  -ms-filter: blur(50px);
  filter: blur(50px);
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  top: 0;
}

span {
  z-index:9999;
  -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
  -moz-filter: blur(0px);
  -o-filter: blur(0px);
  -ms-filter: blur(0x);
  filter: blur(0px);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can use @media queries if you are referring the mobile platform using the screen size. Else you can use javascript to inject an attribute to top of the html tag and by using it you can isolate your css code specific to target devices.

e.g. https://github.com/rafaelp/css_browser_selector

Comment: That browser selector is amazing. Thank you. It's working wonders.

Comment: Welcome. I'm curious, about your answer, what is an example of an @media query?

Comment: Based on browser screen size you can have different styling: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp